# How to install a font in Windows 7

Tags: windows, fonts

I'm trying to install [Source Code Pro](https://github.com/adobe/source-code-pro) and the [Windows documentations](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/install-or-uninstall-fonts) says

> Open Fonts by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button,
>   clicking Control Panel, clicking Appearance and Personalization, and
>   then clicking Fonts.

But I don't see fonts listed.

I was able to install [Anonymous Pro](http://www.marksimonson.com/fonts/view/anonymous-pro) by clicking on the downloaded .ttf file and choosing install, but Source Code Pro is a little different.

-- Edit 1

I was able to get to %windir%\fonts but the next line of the documentation says:

> Click File, and then click Install New Font.

And when I click File, I don't see an "Install New Font" menu option.

-- Edit 2

I just downloaded the font binaries from sourceforge and installed it by clicking on the .ttf file.

Answer (score 0):

Just press start+r on your keyboard and then type **fonts**. Press ok and that's it.